# Сбросить зажатую кнопку

Tags: java

Собственно в коде ниже есть действие по кнопке, оно зацикленно, пока действие не произойдет кнопка будто залипает (зажата) и ничего делать не могу с этим программой. У меня 3 вопроса:

1. Как сказать кнопке что запустила и забудь про цикл отожмись обратно?
2. Как вернуть контроль над программой не прерывая цикл?
3. Как программно прервать подобный цикл допустим через нажатие другой кнопки?

**Часть кода**

```
public class ServerButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        ServerBuilder();
    }           
} // end ServerButton

public void ServerBuilder () {
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket)); // создаем поток и передаем туда клиента
            t.start();
            System.out.println("Got a connection");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Кнопка залипает потому что вы, судя по всему, запускаете сервер в одном и том же потоке с GUI и в итоге он застревает в цикле while, под это нужно выделить отдельный поток, тогда отпадет и второй вопрос.
2. 
3. Например привязав цикл к какому-либо условию на которое вы потом сможете повлиять извне:

   ```
   volatile boolean isActive = true;
   //...
   while (isActive) {
   //...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что **Swing** (который вы скорей всего используете) не является потокобезопасным. Это накладывает следующие ограничения:

1. Все изменения графических компонент должны происходить в специальном потоке - **The Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)**
2. Код который выполняется в **EDT** не должен его блокировать

Ваш код как раз нарушает **второе** ограничение. Подобная конструкция:

```
while (true) {
    // какой-то код 
}
```

полностью блокирует **EDT** и следовательно весь интерфейс перестает реагировать на действия пользователя и обновляться (кнопки не реагируют, возникают артефакты и пр).

Можно вынести Server в отдельный класс:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    private List<PrintWriter> clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean stop = false;
    private ServerSocket server;

    public Server() throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                clientOutputStreams.add(new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                new Thread(new ClientHandler(client)).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // вывести в лог
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (stop) {
            // нет смысла останавливать его еще раз
            return;
        }
        stop = true;
        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // вывести в лог
        }
    }

    public List<PrintWriter> getClientOutputStreams() {
        return clientOutputStreams;
    }
}
```

И по нажатию на кнопку запускать его в отдельном потоке:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    server = new Server();
    new Thread(server).start();
}
```

И останавливать другой кнопкой

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    server.stop();
}
```